# iMac Pro Kernel panic

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I was browsing Google Chrome and switched tabs from Discord to a new tab and then my Mac laptop crashed. I was then greeted with my minimal bash GNU GRUB screen whenever I try to run Linux without the OS hard drive plugged in. Nothing wrong with that screen.

I'm just wondering why my laptop decided to have a seizure.

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80063371b0): "zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone kalloc.8192, likely due to memory leak in zone kalloc.64 (3617955840 total bytes, 56530555 elements allocated)"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.51.2/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2413
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91fb8db7e0 : 0xffffff80062ec3ec 
0xffffff91fb8db860 : 0xffffff80063371b0 
0xffffff91fb8db9b0 : 0xffffff8006837387 
0xffffff91fb8db9e0 : 0xffffff7f88bccf67 
0xffffff91fb8dba00 : 0xffffff7f88b2d1dc 
0xffffff91fb8dba30 : 0xffffff7f88b16297 
0xffffff91fb8dba80 : 0xffffff7f88b1c9ea 
0xffffff91fb8dbae0 : 0xffffff7f88b1dbf0 
0xffffff91fb8dbb20 : 0xffffff80068e3c61 
0xffffff91fb8dbb80 : 0xffffff80068ecc81 
0xffffff91fb8dbcc0 : 0xffffff80063c01f8 
0xffffff91fb8dbdd0 : 0xffffff80062f166c 
0xffffff91fb8dbe30 : 0xffffff80062cdff1 
0xffffff91fb8dbe80 : 0xffffff80062e2667 
0xffffff91fb8dbf10 : 0xffffff80063ed0d8 
0xffffff91fb8dbfb0 : 0xffffff800629dd66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(311.11)[41BE9F49-4998-3297-9EF6-9972DD38B09E]@0xffffff7f88b01000->0xffffff7f88b90fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C6E3195E-A0D7-3B71-B5F4-9EE9E182D4FC]@0xffffff7f86be0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(514.10)[E197EF14-F55B-3B9C-B903-91258C9CA382]@0xffffff7f8798f000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics(10.2.4)[D1DEEF45-4013-31E7-BCE7-97B67875A726]@0xffffff7f88ba0000->0xffffff7f88c14fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(159.6)[85BD985C-2B78-3C1A-9606-6A6B0CB77E24]@0xffffff7f87846000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C6E3195E-A0D7-3B71-B5F4-9EE9E182D4FC]@0xffffff7f86be0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(514.10)[E197EF14-F55B-3B9C-B903-91258C9CA382]@0xffffff7f8798f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(311.11)[41BE9F49-4998-3297-9EF6-9972DD38B09E]@0xffffff7f88b01000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
16E195
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Since you're new, I'll link this to the highest voted question that answers why a kernel panic happens. This hold can be easily reversed if you want to edit in the text of the file or you can ask a follow on question on where the file is stored after a crash if you [can't find that by the linked questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80000/understanding-kernel-panic-error-log). The why is a divide by zero or other illegal instruction. Always.