# Understanding my panic report

Tags: kernel-panic, macos

Macpro, Mid 2010, 12 core, 96GB memory, Running 10.10.5

I am seeing a restart, i.e. coming back to the Mac having rebooted itself, every few days. This is the entire report -

```
Anonymous UUID:       88D54F26-424A-3B8C-8AE0-9E037010D131

Sun Oct 11 11:01:46 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff8007fc14de): "launchd died\nState at Last Exception:\n\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.70.3/bsd/kern/kern_exit.c:363

uuid info:
 0x7fff64ff4000 uuid = <3c068a0d-69d5-3ad6-86d9-6261d3b1564e>
 0x1059a2000    uuid = <c0446878-e8d0-3461-a226-91ff1c2b2da6>
 0x1059f5000    uuid = <4396b358-725e-3ec0-bcbb-e4bf75fe1fb0>

RAX: 0x0000000002000001, RBX: 0x0000000000000006, RCX: 0x0000000108c80108, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0x0000000108c80108, RBP: 0x0000000108c801b0, RSI: 0x0000000108c7ff60, RDI: 0x0000000000000001
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x00000001059e19f0, R10: 0x00007fff90361b02, R11: 0x0000000000000202
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x00007fff8cd6e7e0, R14: 0x0000000108c805f0, R15: 0x0000000108c80790
RFL: 0x0000000000000202, RIP: 0x00007fff9035f95a, CS:  0x0000000000000007, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread  0xffffff80c6989108
    0x00007fff91220d9b
    0x00007fff91220eb8
    0x00007fff9121a3a5
    0x00007fff9378fa6c
    0x00000001059d0907
    0x00007fff93846e73
    0x00007fff93849dc7
    0x00007fff93849a1c
    0x00007fff85926a9d
    0x00007fff859243dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80c6ba45c0
    0x00007fff9384b26e
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80c688f4b8
    0x00000001059b9c91
    0x00007fff93846e73
    0x00007fff9384a5cd
    0x00007fff9384a030
    0x00007fff93849bef
    0x00007fff93849a1c
    0x00007fff85926a9d
    0x00007fff859243dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80c692f000
    0x00007fff9384a925
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80f3165c50
    0x00007fff89120f1a
    0x000000019275f179
    0x00007fff90c9f7b5
    0x00007fff911ef620
    0x00007fff8cd6e7e0
    0x00007fff8cd70ddf
    0x00007fff93846e73
    0x00007fff938478ca
    0x00007fff8cd6f0a7
    0x00000001059cd393
    0x00007fff93846e73
    0x00007fff9384a5cd
    0x00007fff9384a030
    0x00007fff9384a3bc
    0x00007fff9384a030
    0x00007fff93849bef
    0x00007fff93849a1c
    0x00007fff85926a9d
    0x00007fff859243dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80f21e2e28
    0x00007fff9384b1b8
    0x00007fff8592705a
    0x00007fff85926fd7
    0x00007fff859243ed
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80ebd0b798
    0x00007fff859243dd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread  0xffffff80e666ea78
    0x00007fff859243dd
    0x0000000000000000

Mac OS version: 14F2511
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Sun Jun  4 21:40:08 PDT 2017; root:xnu-2782.70.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9CB959EF-B0D4-3046-98E1-53536EA95A4F
System model name: MacPro5,1 (Mac-F221BEC8)
Model: MacPro5,1, BootROM MP51.007F.B03, 12 processors, 6-Core Intel Xeon, 3.33 GHz, 96 GB, SMC 1.39f5
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: DIMM 1, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 2, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 3, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 5, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 6, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Memory Module: DIMM 7, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, -
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f4 17916, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Ethernet 2, Ethernet, en1
PCI Card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120, Display Controller, Slot-1
PCI Card: pci1b4b,9230, AHCI Controller, Slot-2
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Slot-3
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Slot-4
Serial ATA Device: Micron_5100_MTFDDAK3T8TBY, 3.84 TB
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT250MX200SSD1, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVD-RW GH41N
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD60EZRZ-00RWYB1, 6 TB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA HDWN180, 8 TB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA HDWN180, 8 TB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA DT01ACA300, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA HDWF180, 8 TB
Serial ATA Device: spsata_pm_name
Serial ATA Device: MARVELL VIRTUALL
Serial ATA Device: spsata_pm_name
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: HP OfficeJet Pro 8710
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, Up to 800 Mb/sec
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Is there any way to look at this to understand what, exactly, caused this crash/reboot?

Comment: There should be a section farther down which shows the call stack and allows to identify the process/application causing it. It may or may not help though...

Comment: I added the rest of the report I snapped, thx

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/80026/88313) with info on how to read a panic report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is extensive documentation and even support for a second Mac to read and debug the situations that cause these panic logs to be written.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/debugging_a_custom_kernel_extension
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2063/_index.html

You can go as [technical as you wish in analyzing these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108297/5472) or stick to the general tips to triage them.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

Comment: Thank you. The worst part is the infrequency of this occurring. Now 6 days with no issue.